# Memory Leak on Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeWaitHandle?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks

So I am profiling my application with ANTS memory profiler and the large object heap size goes back down after I run my test, but the private bytes do not seem to fully go back down.

It says that there are many SafeWaitHandles left over and also System.Threading.OverlappedData suggesting that there is a problem with the finalizer of overlapped data.

I am desperately trying to make this application rock solid so that it can be left running forever (I will probably put in a fail safe restart if memory usage hits a certain value anyway)

Has anyone had any experience with these objects causing problems?

Also System.Configuration.RunetimeConfigurationRecord is storing a lot of strings which appear to be taking up quite a lot of memory. But i'm not quite sure about what to do with this either. I can provide any information / dumps that may help.

Thanks in advance. Chris

Comment: How much is it taking up exactly?  Are we talking about dozen MB or something larger?  Are you making sure you clean up after yourself when you are done with the SafeWaitHandle?

Comment: if i make 500 tcp connections then disconnect them all theres an additional 2-4 meg of private memory. I dont know where safewaithandle comes from, but there appears to be a problem with it staying in memory.

Comment: what is system.threading.overlappeddata?

Comment: Chris - 2-4MB of memory isn't anything to worry about.  Have you tried to clear the RunetimeConfigurationRecord by chance ( never used it myself ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

old question which is no longer a problem - the service memory usage fluctuates by a few meg but after extensive testing happy that there are no memory leaks & fail safes with service failure configuration sufficient. will accept this as answer when allowed.